# Java - Spring Boot - Mysql: Dockerizando aplicación y base de datos

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

Hola tengo que dockerizar mi proyecyo de springboot + sql  y soy nuevo en eso de usar docker.Necesitaria ayuda.

**APPLICATION PROPERTIES:**

```
spring.datasource.url=${DATABASE_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${DATABASE_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
# Utiliza una imagen de OpenJDK 17 con HotSpot JVM y basada en Ubuntu Bionic (versión slim)
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine

ENV DATABASE_URL jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.1:3306/clinica_odontologica
ENV DATABASE_USERNAME root
ENV DATABASE_PASSWORD admin


# Copia el archivo JAR construido en la fase de construcción
COPY target/Clinica-Odontologica-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar clinica-odontologica.jar

# Comando para ejecutar la aplicación al iniciar el contenedor
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "clinica-odontologica.jar"]
```

**Docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  clinica-odontologica:
    container_name: clinica-odontologica
    image: pee-clinica-odontologica:1.0.0
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=jdbc:mysql://clinica_odontologica_db:3306/clinica_odontologica
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=root
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=admin
    depends_on:
      - clinica_odontologica_db

  clinica_odontologica_db:
    container_name: clinica-odontologica_db
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: "root"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "admin"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "clinica_odontologica"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "admin"

volumes:
  mysql-data:
    external: false
```

Tengo varios errores si yo utilizo en mi docker-compose.yml en el servicio de clinica_odontologica_db el puerto 3306:3306. Quiero hacer un docker-compose up me tira el error de...

> Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP
> 0.0.0.0:3306 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: Solo se permite un uso de cada dirección de socket (protocolo/d irección de
> red/puerto)

Entonces cambie el puerto a 3307:3306 donde ahi puedo usar el docker-compose up pero cuando compila me dice que

> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications
> link failure